# Probabllility of a single trial given the probability of two random trials..

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I came across a statement while reading an article. Please explain me these statements

```
Pr[y1,y2]  [f(x+y1) - f(y1) = f(x+y2) - f(y2)] > 5/9
```

> Since we have two identical random trials that are equal with
>   probability > 5/9, this implies that the most common value of a single
>   trial occurs with probability greater than 2/3 (since to agree they
>   must choose either the most common value or some other value).

How do the got the value 2/3???

note pr[y1,y2] : y1,y2 was given under pr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let q be the probability of the most common event and let p be the probability that your two trials agree.  Then we have:  $$ p ≤ q^2 + (1-q)^2$$  since the right hand is the probability that either the two trials both hit the most common event or that they both miss it (clearly an upper bound for p coinciding only when there are only two possible outcomes).  But the right side of the inequality is only above $\frac 59$ if $q > \frac 23$.

Comment: could you please say what equation is "p ≤ q^2 + (1-q)^2"

Comment: Not sure how to answer that.  The right side is the sum of two probabilities: A. The probability that the two trials both hit the common event and B. the probability that neither does.  p, the probability that they match, is the sum of A plus the probabilities that they match at some other value (not the most common one).  But all those latter events require that both miss the common one so they are all part of B.  Of course, B probably contains other cases (one trial gets event #2, the other gets event #3 and so on) so it is an inequality.